# How To Make An App install in the SD Card

Tags: android, storage

I am new to java, my application takes alot of space, and i would like to install it in SD card (prefer). could anybody help me with this? any help will be appreciated 
Thanks!

Comment: It amuses me that your profile location is set to `Sd_Card`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot force your app to install on the SD card, but you can *request* that the device install the app on the SD card. You do this in your manifest using the `android:installLocation` attribute like so:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

For more, see the [App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) documentation.